# Not spanning Wallpaper across dual screen

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, compiz, desktop-background

With compiz plugin Wallpaper on ubuntu 16.04, the wallpaper spans across dual monitors automatically.
How to disable this? I would like to simply duplicate the wallpaper on both screen.

Answer (score 0):

#### 18.04 and later

1. Install Tweaks with `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` and open Tweaks.
2. Select *Appearance*.
3. Click the ▾ arrow to show the dropdown menu as marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot. Change the span option to *Zoom*.

[image]

#### 16.04

1. Open System Settings by clicking the gear icon on the Launcher.
2. Select *Appearance* -> *Look* tab.
3. Click the ▾ arrow to show the dropdown menu as shown in the below screenshot. Change the *Span* option to *Zoom*.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Simply right click on your wallpaper image file. And click on "Set as Wallpaper" option. That's it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/880749)

Comment: @thomas, thanks. I will definitely try to answer questions that don't require clarification till I get sufficient reputation. The answer I provided worked for me. Hence answered.